# How to convert hex value into integer with it's ascii translation in Python?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I need to convert a hexadecimal number into an integer.

I have `n=2`, then used `newN=hex(n)` which gave me the value `0x32`. Now i'm trying to re convert it to it's integer value using `int(newN,16)` but that is giving me nothing, it just gives me an empty string. 
I also tried `chr(int(newN,16))` but same result.

Here's a testing code

```
n = '2'
newN = hex(n)
print(str(newN))
oldN = chr(int(newN, 16))
print(str(oldN))
```

I'm getting the following:

```
0x32
```

Comment: Your code works fine just change `hex(n)` to `hex(ord(n))` at 2nd line.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is incorrect `n` variable is of type string(of length 1), rather then an integer. (because it corresponds to hex value 50 which is equivalent of '2' in ASCII)

**CODE:-**

```
n = '2'

# Ord(n) gives us the Unicode code point of the given character ('2' = 50)
# hex() produces its hexadecimal equivalent (50 = "0x32")
n_hex = hex(ord(n))

# 0x32
print(n_hex)

# Ord(n) gives us the Unicode code point of the given character ('2' = 50) 
n_hex_int = ord(n)

# 50
print(n_hex_int)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
0x32
50
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah. n is a string. So how can i get that 50 from 0x32 in order to get the 2 i need?

Comment: `int("0x32", 16)` = 50; `chr(50)` = '2'

Comment: I tried exactly that, but the result is stil `('')` (empty string), don't know why.